# Математические встроенные функции PHP

Tags: php, статистика

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос такой, сижу программирую на OpenServer, версия PHP 5.4. После чего открываю мануал PHP, и пытаюсь использовать статические функции от языка программирования - stats_variance, stats_stat_factorial, stats_stat_correlation и другие процедуры.

Однако почему-то вызывается ошибка в коде, что данная функция не найдена.

Вот собственно адрес перечня статического многообразия от PHP: [Список](https://php.net/manual/ru/ref.stats.php)
В чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/stats.installation.php `Это расширение » PECL не поставляется вместе с PHP.`

Comment: Программировать на php 5.4 - прошлый век.

Comment: @ArchDemon, что же предложите для работы?

Comment: @vp_arth, Например в OpenServer как добавить расширение PECL?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: Перейти на новую версию OpenServer? Или переключить на php 7, если имеется такая возможность в этом дистрибутиве